# How to keep Azure Function available during code updates?

Tags: python, azure, continuous-integration, azure-functions, continuous-deployment

I've found that my Azure Function is unavailable for approx. 3-5 mins when publishing changes. Any triggers are not recognized nor captured in App Insights.

This is not a big deal at the moment, but if this Function ever requires increased uptime, how can I ensure it will be available during code changes?

Comment: One way is to use the deployment slots:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you just need to use the [Azure Functions deployment slots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots), when you need to publish the changes, swap your function to the staging slot, after publishing, swap it back to the production slot.

Comment: Then I'd proceed to update the code in the staging slot, is that correct? How do I select a deployment slot when running `azure functionapp publish <function-name>  --publish-local-settings`? I don't see the words "deployment slot" on [this doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=linux%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#project-file-deployment).

Comment: @SeaDude Yes, you need to treat the slot as a independent app, its name has the format like `functionname-slotname`, so just use `azure functionapp publish <functionname-slotname>`.